# Sum merged cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Okay so i'm making a pretty basic shopping list for one of my hobby projects, and i wanted to make it look a bit fancier, hence this.

But i can't seem to figure out how to work with merged cells. If you look at [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIVCe.png), this is what i'm trying to do: 
**The first red cell should be multiplied with the first blue cell, the second red cell multiplied with the second blue cell and so on and on. All of that should then be added up and displayed in the green cell.**

P.S, please ignore the € signs everywhere! The cells should be treated as regular plain numbers as i'm using file formatting to make those € signs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no numbers elsewhere in ColumnsH:K,  try:

```
=sumproduct(H6:H15,K6:K15)
```

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately, it throws an #ERROR!

Comment: Okay. The x's are formatting, so they should be ignored. The first red cell is H6:J7, second is H13:J14. First blue cell is K6:N7, second is K13:N14

Comment: I did try =SUMPRODUCT(H13:N14; H6:N7) which worked, but gave the wrong result (63, when it should have been 36)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer actually. Just treat them as normal cells (non-merged) and it works.

```
=ADD(MULTIPLY(H6;K6);MULTIPLY(H13;K13))
```

Works perfectly